# Running DaVinci on an HP Proliant server without OpenGL or CUDA GPU

Tags: drivers, graphics-card, gpu, hp-proliant, hp

I have an old HP ProLiant server running Windows 10 where I would like to install and run DaVinci Resolve. I install the latest version, 18, and see

```
CRITICAL_QUIT: GPU initialization failed could not initialize OpenGL
```

Following [these tips](https://videowithjens.com/fix-unable-to-initialize-gpu-in-davinci-resolve/), I download and install version 16, and I see:

```
DaVinci Resolve could not find any OpenCL capable GPUs.
```

I could find little about the graphics card. Here is a screenshot from `System Information`:

[image: screenshot of graphics card details]

A previous owner tried to change the graphics card but it turned to be very difficult due to HP's safeguards.

How can I run DaVinci Resolve on this computer? Can I install a program to emulate a GPU?

Comment: How are you accessing it? Many 'RDP' type structures cannot use the remote GPU, they have an emulation instead. The workaround if you can get to the machine itself is to launch it locally, before remoting into it. DaVinci will run on Open GL 2.1 & doesn't require CUDA.

Comment: @Tetsujin The 2007 integrated ATI ES1000 only supports OpenGL 1.0

Comment: @ChanganAuto - … ouch ;) Are we certain, though, that's the hardware or an emulation? 'Basic Display Adaptor' is the kind of data you get from an emulation that can't quite figure itself out. TBH, if that is a 2007 machine you really don't want to be trying to edit video on it. 1024x768@1Hz also looks suspect - I doubt the interface would even open into that.

Comment: I can access it locally and through Remote Desktop Protocol. On the screenshot, I only captured the local display, not the RDP display, but I can include that as well. I believe "Basic Display Adaptor" is the hardware, yes. the 1024x768@1Hz interface is an old monitor I attached to the server. The Resolve interface does launch, yes, and I can edit the basic configuration.

Comment: @Tetsujin I'm going by the "adapter type" that I think it's the real hardware. Working with Microsoft Basic Display Adapter is also expected because support for this chips was dropped a long time ago. The same happened with newer and discrete Nvidia GPUs, at least in 32-bit OSes.

Comment: @ChanganAuto - I'm going to have to go with your expertise on this one. I don't know the specifics for this particular instance. [I discovered this basic premise when I used to run a Windows game over RDP from a Mac. Lauch it before remoting in & it works. Launch it over remote & it fails with "inadequate GPU".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your HP Proliant server is way below the [minimum system requirements for the current DaVinci Resolve.](https://ifilmthings.com/davinci-resolve-system-requirements/#davinci_resolve_system_requirements_for_windows)

Namely:

- Discrete or integrated GPU of at least 2GB of VRAM.
- GPU that supports **CUDA 11** or **OpenCL** – and a GPU driver version that will support the GPU, either an AMD, Intel or NVIDIA.

Now compare the aforementioned requirements with the specifications of your 2007 integrated [ATI ES1000](https://www.techpowerup.com/gpu-specs/es1000.c2102):

- OpenCL: N/A

The shared VRAM is set by the firmware (BIOS or UEFI) and  even in the extremely unlikely event it could be set to the "at least 2GB of VRAM" requirement, that wouldn't make sense for a server of this class.

In conclusion, the error message `GPU initialization failed could not initialize OpenGL` is to be expected.